# When form submitting and the page refreshing my loading screen comes in agin?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, forms

I am trying to create a login page. I made a loading screen that fades when the page loads.

```
        $(window).on("load",function(){
            setTimeout(function() { 
                $(".loading").fadeOut("slow", function(){
                    $(".container").fadeIn("slow").css("display", "flex");
                });     
            }, 500);
        });
```

The problem is there when you submit a form and the page refreshes because then the loading screen comes in again. Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent the form from submitting with

```
$("#prospects_form").submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
})
```

Without jQuery:

```
var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
function handleForm(event) { event.preventDefault(); } 
form.addEventListener('submit', handleForm);
```

Comment: if i use preventDefault how do i check login in php?

Comment: you have to send the http request with the data yourself with tools like jQuery, fetch, XMLHttpRequest or else. If you don't prevent the default behaviour of the form submission you won't be able to prevent a new loading of the page

Answer (score 0):

1- You can use Ajax for sending the form to the server.

2- Or do something like this:

```
// add an item to session before form submitting.
$(document).on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    sessionStorage.setItem('notLoad', '1')
    $('form').submit() // add any attr to form idetifier.
})

$(window).on('load', function () {
    // check the session to know if the page loaded from form submitting or not:
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('notLoad') !== '1') {
        sessionStorage.removeItem('notLoad');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.loading').fadeOut('slow', function () {
                $('.container').fadeIn('slow').css('display', 'flex')
            })
        }, 500)
    }
})
```